# Delete an app's data folder in /data/data without root or factory reset?

Tags: android, adb

I am having the [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED] problem detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277422/android-install-failed-uid-changed).  The answer suggests deleting the `/data/data/package.name` folder because remnants of a previous installation are still lingering.  The problem is, I don't have root on the phone I am using so I don't have permission to delete that folder.

Comment: Need root to access data folders, and even then it is risky business if you don't know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @zgc7009 Does factory reset not clear out `/data/data`?

Comment: wipe should clear everything BUT SD card data. So yes, it should clear your applications data. Didn't see that you tried that in your original post or would have mentioned that should work. It can only be done dynamically, however, if you have root.

Comment: A factory reset certainly should have gotten rid of `/data/data/package.name/`, assuming that the package name is yours and is not shared by an app in the firmware.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right, a factory reset did delete it.  Is this possible without factory resetting though?

Comment: Not the packagename folder itself. But all folders and files in it can be deleted by an app with that package name without needing root. Only the lib directory in it is read only.

Comment: Once you're in that stuck situation, where the device thinks it removed the app but did not do so completely, I think you're screwed without rooting or factory resetting. I haven't had this happen to me personally, so there may be some other option I am not aware of, but it's no different than "how do I mess around with the files for some arbitrary app", which isn't possible without superuser privileges.

Comment: Unfortunately, a factory reset or a wipe deletes the data from **all apps**. So, if you were at hig scores in your games... you have to restart playing from 0. This would make me nervous.

Comment: @mattblang please check my answer ,if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using `adb shell` and running `pm clear <package.name>` will not work unless you have root permissions.
However, I found another workaround along the same lines:
I booted in recovery mode and then used `adb shell`. I renamed (and eventually deleted) the app data folder `/data/data/<package.name>`