# How to solve ADB error [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED] on non-rooted phone?

Tags: android, apk, adb

I get the error using the Android Studio (but I get the same if I use ADB from command line).

Every solution I found says that I need to delete the installation folder on the phone:

```
adb shell rm -r /data/data/com.example.my
```

but I get a `permission denied` error.

So what can I do on non rooted device?

(I can't delete the folder from device file browser, the folder /data is empty)

The app is **not listed** in the Android app manager

```
adb uninstall com.example.my
```

gives

```
Failure
```

Comment: Just uninstall the app through the app manager. If don't forget to "Uninstall for all Users" if you're on a tablet version of JB+.

Comment: @323go I updated my question, can't see it listed in the app manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the only fix I have found for a non-rooted phone is to wipe the device and start again. The reason this is happening will be because the folder still exists with one file that wasn't deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
adb shell pm clear MY_PACKAGE_NAME
```

or maybe this:

```
adb install -l -r <'apk_name'>.apk -l = forward lock -r = reinstall
```

Comment: adb install -l -r <'apk_name'>.apk -l = forward lock -r = reinstall try this too.

Comment: same result, failure again

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you uninstall the app using:

```
adb uninstall com.example.my
```

This question is related: [Android INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277422/android-install-failed-uid-changed)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I forgot to say that the command give a failure response.

Comment: If you can't find your app in the /data/ folder and you can't uninstall it I think it is not installed. You should find another reason for the installation error

Comment: I can't browse the /data folder because (I think) is not a rooted device

Comment: @seraphims The easiest way to check if it is a rooted device is:
`adb shell` and then `su`