# INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED when android application is run in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I run the application it gives me an error message in console, the error message follows:

```
[2015-12-15 13:24:08 - OrderProCochin] Android Launch!
[2015-12-15 13:24:08 - OrderProCochin] adb is running normally.
[2015-12-15 13:24:08 - OrderProCochin] Performing    com.aitrich.android.framework.ui.activities.impl.SplashActivity activity launch
[2015-12-15 13:24:08 - OrderProCochin] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2015-12-15 13:24:14 - OrderProCochin] Uploading OrderProCochin.apk onto device '0123456789ABCDEF'
[2015-12-15 13:24:16 - OrderProCochin] Installing OrderProCochin.apk...
[2015-12-15 13:24:18 - OrderProCochin] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED
[2015-12-15 13:24:18 - OrderProCochin] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2015-12-15 13:24:18 - OrderProCochin] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Did you `check logcat output for more details`?

Comment: Did you search Google? This StackOverflow question popped up when I did: [Android INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277422/android-install-failed-uid-changed)

Comment: yes but did not get anything