# How to solve Android error on lunching app in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

**I'm getting this error when i'm lunching my app:**

```
Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existin
version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

I clicked 'OK' but then i'm getting this log message:

```
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.team.saver.app"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.team.saver.app
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.team.saver.app
Unknown failure (Failure)
```

- i'v managed to overcome it by replacing the appId, but i need to keep the current app id and not replaced it.
- i also tried deleting the package with adb and did not got response at all from the shell:

  `adb shell rm -rf com.team.saver.app`
- also tried to restart the device

But still cant find a solution, any help would be great, thanx!

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app manually? (settings -> applications...)

Comment: your app is not uninstall successfully. check this--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277422/android-install-failed-uid-changed

Comment: @AmarbirSingh in android monitor i cant open the data folder, and in adb shell i dont get any response when i tried to delete /data/local/tmp/com.team.saver.app

Comment: @Eli there are many solutions in the link none of the 1 works for you.

Comment: i'm trying now to upgrade to version 2.0, will send notification soon

Comment: well i'v tried to upgrade android studio to version 2.0 and it seems that it is still happening. no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install android studio with proper installation of jdk .It will not generate errors if all paths are set ok.

Answer (score 0):

Change you Old SDK version to latest upgrade version and then clean the project and run it again. It may solve the problem .

Comment: I dont have Instant Run in my android studio version 1.5.1

Comment: well i'v tried to upgrade android studio to version 2.0 and it seems that it is still happening. no solution yet.

Comment: @Eli not Android Studio your SDK version.

Comment: i have the latest one. 25.1.1