# Cannot Update App from PlayStore : Error -504

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have published my app on Google Play. If install its works fine, but not able to update app ,  I get the same error code, error 504.

**Error -504 while installing com.xxxx.xxx: INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.xxxx.xxx**

for logs :
E/installd: Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl15380*****.tmp: No such file or directory

**new version**
/data/app/vmdl15380*****.tmp/lib/arm/libmain.so: crc = f43565f4, zipCrc = 4097140212

**old version:**
/data/app/com.xxxx.xxx/lib/arm/libmain.so: crc = 83fdc919, zipCrc = 2214447385

Upgraded unity vesion 2017.4.35f1 to 2019.4.12f1 I used gradle setup for project - mainTemplate.gradle

[image]

After upgrade made changes to
apply plugin: 'com.android.applicaiton' to

apply plugin: '**com.android.library**'
and removed applicationId 'com.xxxx.xxx'

May be this cause issue ? Any idea ?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277422/android-install-failed-uid-changed#:~:text=In%20most%20cases%20INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT%20or,current%20version%20of%20your%20app.)?

Comment: Yes , tried its not working and its from playstore  already has more users ,